# Await several async functions, but continue when one finishes

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to write a function that searches using 2 algorithms. The main function should call both main algorithm functions simultaneously, but continue as soon as one finishes. It should also stop the other function from running.

I currently have an entry function set up like this:

```
async function entry(code) {

    let [ product_algorithm_1, product_algorithm_2 ] = await Promise.all([
        get_info_algorithm_1(code),
        get_info_algorithm_2(code)
    ])

    // Here I would check which variable is not empty, and display the results
}
```

This works fine, but the issue is that it waits for both functions to finish before continuing. I'm trying to continue when one finishes, and deleting the others process. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Probably `Promise.race` is your decision? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is `Promise.race()`. It will return when one of the calls has resolved. Find out more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race).

```js
async function entry(code) {

    let product_algorithm_fastest = await Promise.race([
        get_info_algorithm_1(code),
        get_info_algorithm_2(code)
    ])
}
```

Its worth noting that the returned value will be that of the promise that was "fastest"